# Unity 3d build size too large

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, apk, virtual-reality

I am working on a unity project where the apk built is almost 200mb and the android phones is running it very slow.

I have already tried texture compression and I have brought down the size. Any other suggestions?

The frame rate is slow. My textures are at 256 compressed and PVRTC. Any suggestions, please.

I have read somewhere that I can load only what is needed, anybody who can help me with that ?
1.It is an autowalk cardboard type apk,the player triggers the button to walk.
2.I have imported a fully built house from maya.That is the largest import.The size of which is 800mb.
3.I used the profiler and it looks like the rendering is using too much of CPU.I see many apps that are professional built with even better graphics.Wonder how thats done.
@Joe Blow - Thanks for the edit suggestions, im new here :)

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wvxQ.png - editor log

Comment: Unity automatically ignore assets that are not used in scenes. Try to check your assets, maybe e.g sound files are set up to WAVE instead of OGG. In sound files that can make difference. There are a lot of things that can be optimized it's really hard to tell what exactly causes the problem. Try to search for "unity mobile optimization" you can find many articles about that.

Comment: Avoid using the Resources folder if you don't need to. Everything in it will automatically be built with the project even if it is never used.

Comment: Hi Saranya.  Click "EDIT" on your question and add this information: (1) what sort of project it is (example "car racing game", "dinosaur egg game" etc).  (2) Explain your five largest assets.  (3) include a general screenshot of the game.  (4) include a screenshot of your "Project" panel to get an idea

Comment: Can you post part of the editor log where it lists your build file sizes? https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ReducingFilesize.html

Comment: @Mylsaak - I am not sure what you mean by the "resources" folder.Though there is one in my editor log.I dont see one in my assets.The resource i believe is the house with details. - thanks

Answer (score 4):

Try to do this, go to edit -> player setting -> other setting -> configuration -> device filter  and change it to ARMv7 architecture and then build again your file will get reduce .If you Combine ARMv7 and x86 both architecture in a single apk then your file will get dobule

Comment: Thanks,That has reduced the size to about 150mb,Still big but made a difference :)